# How to copy non-bounded method as bounded in class instance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming

I have a code where I want to 'steal' methods of other class in run-time. (It's a small game and I want to allow bots to change strategy on-demand).

Example:

```
class X(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 1


class Y(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 2
```

I want to 'copy' Y.foo into instance of X class:

```
x.foo = Y.foo
x.foo()  # unbound method
x.foo = types.MethodType(Y.foo, x)
x.foo()  # TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with Y instance as first argument (got X instance instead
tmp=x.foo.__self__
x.foo=Y.foo
x.foo.__self__ = tmp  # readonly attribute
x.foo.__func__ = Y.bar.__func__ # readonly attribute
```

Is there any way to copy function from one class into other in runtime, without:

1. Inheritance (it should be done inside method of instanced class)
2. calling `Y.bar` from within `x.foo`

Comment: Have you looked at the Strategy Pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, accessing a method on the class returns an unbound method. Simply unwrap that method to get the original function, using the `__func__` attribute:

```
x.foo = types.MethodType(Y.foo.__func__, x)
```

You could tell that function to bind using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html):

```
x.foo = Y.foo.__func__.__get__(x)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         return 1
...
>>> class Y(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         return 2
...
>>> x = X()
>>> Y.foo
<unbound method Y.foo>
>>> Y.foo.__func__
<function foo at 0x1006d1b18>
>>> Y.foo.__func__.__get__(x)
<bound method ?.foo of <__main__.X object at 0x1006e84d0>>
>>> x.foo = Y.foo.__func__.__get__(x)
>>> x.foo()
2
```